# Fourier Series of $f(x) = 0$ from $(−1,0)$ , $3x$ from $(0,1)$ , f=(x+2)

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I need to determine the Fourier series of the following function.

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } -1 < x < 0 \\ 3x & \text{if } \phantom{{}-{}} 0 \le x < 1 \end{cases}.$$

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? Does it have period $2$?

Comment: Right, you need this, but *what is your question?*

Answer (score 1):

**Define problem**

*Piecewise function*: Resolve $f(x)$ into a left and right piece

$$
\begin{align}
  %
  l(x) &= 0, \quad -\lambda \le x < 0 \\
  %
  r(x) &= 3x, \quad \  0 \le x \le \lambda
  %
\end{align}
$$

[image: pieces]

Find the Fourier expansion
$$ 
  f(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_{0} +
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(
  a_{k} \cos \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) +
  b_{k} \sin \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right)
\right)
$$
where $\lambda = 1$ for this problem.

Given $k=1,2,3\dots$, the amplitudes are given by

$$
\begin{align}
  %
  a_{0} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} f(x) dx \\
  %
  a_{k} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} f(x) \cos \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) dx \\
  %
  b_{k} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} f(x) \sin \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x  \right) dx \\
  %
\end{align}
$$

**Basic integrals**

*Left hand piece*

$$
\begin{align}
  %
  \int_{-\lambda}^{0} l(x) dx &= 0 \\
  %
  \int_{-\lambda}^{0} l(x) \cos \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) dx &= 0 \\
  %
  \int_{-\lambda}^{0} l(x) \sin \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) dx &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

*Right hand piece*

$$
\begin{align}
  %
  \int_{0}^{\lambda} r(x) dx &= \frac{3}{2} \\
  %
  \int_{0}^{\lambda} r(x) \cos \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) dx &= \frac{3 \left((-1)^k-1\right)}{\pi ^2 k^2} \\
  %
  \int_{0}^{\lambda} r(x) \sin \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda}x \right) dx &= -\frac{3 (-1)^k}{\pi  k}
  %
\end{align}
$$

**Results**

$$
\begin{align}
  %
    a_{0} & = \frac{3}{2} \\
  %
    a_{k} &= \frac{3 \left((-1)^k-1\right)}{\pi ^2 k^2} \\[2pt]
  %
    b_{k} &= -\frac{3 (-1)^k}{\pi  k}
  %
  %
\end{align}
$$

The first terms of each series:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\left\{ a_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{7} &=
-\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}
\left\{
1,0,\frac{1}{9},0,\frac{1}{25},0,\frac{1}{49}
\right\} \\[5pt]
%
\left\{ b_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{7} &=
\frac{3}{\pi}
\left\{ 
1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7}
\right\}
%
\end{align}
$$

**Approximation sequence**

$$
 g_{n}(x) = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{\pi}
 \sum_{k=1}^{n} 
\left(
  \frac{(-1)^k-1}{\pi  k^2} \cos \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda} x \right) + 
  \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin \left( \frac{k \pi} {\lambda} x \right)
\right)
$$

**Visual verification**

[image: n=1]
[image: n=3]
[image: n=5]
[image: n=100]

**Periodicity**

[image: repeat]